# jQuery hide and show html textboxs with modified max length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with my code. I am suppose to have a drop downList and two textfields. The textFields should have Max lengths. Whenever I click on a specific option in the dropdown one of the textFields should hide. The other textfield should remain. however with a new max length and if I choose the other option in my drop downList both textfields should appear with their original max length. My code is not working 100% whenever i revert from my option1 to option2 the max length just keeps on going forever in my first textfield.

```
enter code here

<select id="choices1">
<option value="chooose">chooose</option>
<option value="option1">first option</option>
<option value="option2">second option</option>
</select> 
<br>
<input type="text" id="textbox1" maxlength="9"  placeholder="type here"> 
<br>
<input type="text" id="textbox2" maxlength="13"  placeholder="type here">
```

$('#choices1').on('change', function(){

```
 if ( $( '#textbox2' ).data( 'originalMaxLength' ) == '' ) {

$( '#textbox2' ).data( 'originalMaxLength', $('#textbox2').attr('13') ); 

    } 

 if($(this).val()=="option2"){

$('#textbox2').hide(); 
 $( '#textbox1' ).attr( 'maxlength', '5' );

} 

else{
    $('#textbox2').show(); 
    console.log($('#textbox1').data('originalMaxLength'));
    $('#textbox1').attr('maxlength',$('#textbox1').data('originalMaxLength')=='13')
    $('#textbox1').val('');    
}
```

});

Comment: `$('#textbox2').attr('13')` should be `$('#textbox2').attr('maxlength')`

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ckn6kuxn/